# how get the Html data ckEditor on client?preview result by change character on client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ckeditor

I am having problem to get data html written in ckeditor in Jquery.
I can't select data by jQuery because this editor loading file after $(document).ready()
I get data and post by $.ajax{} to db , and show in preview section.

(c# / asp.net)

my problem:
I can't get elementID.

i use the ckeditor by add dll to toolbox.

ckeditor in html code

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditorControl" runat="server"  
            BasePath="ckeditor" ContentsCss="ckeditor/contents.css" 
            Height="250px" 
            TemplatesFiles="ckeditor/themes/default/theme.js" FilebrowserBrowseUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" 
            FilebrowserFlashBrowseUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" FilebrowserFlashUploadUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" 
            FilebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" FilebrowserImageBrowseUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" 
            FilebrowserImageUploadUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" 
            FilebrowserUploadUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" BackColor="#FF0066" 
                    DialogButtonsOrder="Rtl" 
                    FontNames="B Yekan; B Yekan,tahoma;Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive; Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace; Georgia/Georgia, serif; Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif; Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif; Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" 
                    ResizeDir="Vertical" ResizeMinHeight="350" UIColor="#CACACA">dhd fdh</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

can any one help me out?

===========================
method in core.ckeditor.js

```
getData : function()
        {
            this.fire( 'beforeGetData' );
 
            var eventData = this._.data;

            if ( typeof eventData != 'string' )
            {
                var element = this.element;
                if ( element && this.elementMode == CKEDITOR.ELEMENT_MODE_REPLACE )
                    eventData = element.is( 'textarea' ) ? element.getValue() : element.getHtml();
                else
                    eventData = '';
            }

            eventData = { dataValue : eventData };
 
            // Fire "getData" so data manipulation may happen.
            this.fire( 'getData', eventData );
 
            return eventData.dataValue;
        }
```

description:

```
{String} getData() Since: 3.0
Gets the editor data. The data will be in raw format. It is the same data that is posted by the editor. 
Defined in: core/editor.js.
if ( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData() == '' )
    alert( 'There is no data available' );
Returns:
{Undefined} (String) The editor data.
```

i writed code:

html:

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

js:

```
var edit = CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
        alert(CKEDITOR.instances.edit.getData());
```

But not happend?

Comment: Did you try `CKEDITOR.instances.editorinstance.getData()`

Comment: tanks.not worked.in the CKEDITOR.instances.editorinstance.getData(),editorinstance what's?

Comment: That is the value you pass to `CKEDITOR.replace('editorinstance');`, but I don't know if that is done when used with asp.net

Comment: not worked.i writed: ' var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditorControl');    
    alert(CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData()); '

Comment: Try `CKEDITOR.instances.CKEditorControl.getData()`

Comment: not work.getData() noting get back.same return false.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
alert(CKEDITOR.instances.<%=CKEditorControl.ClientID %>.getData());
```

It works.

Comment: Please describe your answer more so it can help more StackOverflow members :)